# ES6 inheritance force base class to only call its own members

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Using the following example, is there a way for 'this' of the Base to always refer to the Base class? Currently the value of 'this' depends on whether Base was called directly or by the class extending it.

Not having `action()` as part of `Derived` isn't an option, it's there and it's a higher form of the `Base`'s `action()` for a reason.

Does this behavior look counter intuitive just to me (too much is c# possibly)?

```
class Base {
        do() {
            console.error(this.action()); // I say 'this' meaning Base should execute its own action(), and never derived one.
        }

        action() {
            return "Base";
        }
    }

    class Derived extends Base {
        action() {
            throw "Derived";
        }
    }

    new Base().do();
    new Derived().do();
```

Comment: That is fundamentally how inheritance is supposed to work. See [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open–closed_principle).

Comment: It already works the way you describe it. Do you have a question?

Comment: @slebetman Not quite, I would expect that 'this' used from inside Base to always point at Base's methods, while it seems to depend of the context of invocation.

Comment: `this` refers to the *instance*, not the class. Overriding a parent's method is explicitly "a thing" and `this` referring to the instance is the mechanism that makes it work.

Comment: Yes. Even in C++ and Java the code above would work the same. I don't know about C# but I assume it would also print "Derived" if you do `new Derived().do()` unless C# does not have class inheritance and only interface inheritance like go. The only language that works the way I think you mean is go but you would need to reimplement `do()` in both classes because that's just how go works

Comment: @deceze - c# is doing it differently, I put code into a dummy answer. I find it having more sense tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
class Base {
  do() {
    console.log(Base.prototype.action.call(this));
  }

  action() {
    return "Base";
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  action() {
    throw "Derived";
  }
}

new Base().do();
new Derived().do();
```

This explicitly picks the specific class' method and calls it with the context set appropriately to the current instance.

However, this appears like hyper-defensive programming. A class should be [*open to extension*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), not bend over backwards to prevent extension. If a child overrides a method, it's up to it to call or not call the parent's implementation. If it has a reason to override a method, then it has its reason.

If anything it would make sense to have a *private* method which only the implementing class itself is meant to call, and even derived classes should not call. [Private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) are a recent experiment, but some naming convention can do the same:

```
class Base {
    __private_action() {
        ...
    }

    do() {
        this.__private_action();
    }
}
```

Note that it's still entirely possible to override this if you really want to, but the leading-underscore naming convention signals a "don't touch that", which should be good enough among consenting adults. It's a waste of energy trying to be overly defensive, as there's no truly "private" code in the first place, especially not in a dynamic language like Javascript.